# This code kills the page

Tags: coffeescript

I have a function

```
makeMarks: (first, nextIncrement, classifier) ->
    results = new Array()

    t = first(@minT)
    while t<=@maxT
        mark = 
            t: t
            x: this.tToX(t)
            class: classifier(t)

        results.push(mark)

        t = nextIncrement(t)

    results
```

this function works great with the following two functions as parameters

```
# parameters for hour tickmarks
@firstHour = (t) ->
    msPerHour = 1000*60*60
    Math.floor(t / msPerHour) * msPerHour

@nextHour = (currentHour) ->
    msPerHour = 1000*60*60
    currentHour + msPerHour
```

when called as such

```
marks = markMaker.makeMarks( @firstMonth, @nextMonth, @classifier)
```

Now to the problem:

```
# parameters for month tickmarks
@firstMonth = (minT) ->
msPerDay = 1000*60*60*24
t = Math.floor(minT/msPerDay) * msPerDay
d = new Date(t)
while(d.getDate() isnt 0)
        t += msPerDay
        d.setTime(t)
t

@nextMonth = (currentMonth) ->
msPerDay = 1000*60*60*24
t = currentMonth + msPerDay
d = new Date(t)
while(d.getDate() isnt 0)
        t += msPerDay
        d.setTime(t)
t
```

The hour code works fine, but the month code doesn't seem to terminate.

Comment: I don't know anything about coffee script, but when would `d.getDate()` ever become `0` when it is always being incremented? Would this be your infinite loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The getDate function never returns 0. Its minimum value is 1 and it's maximum value is 31. If you're looking for anything outside that range, that's a long wait for a train that don't come.